# Too much DB tables with CakePHP because of his lack of ENUM support

Tags: database, design-patterns, cakephp

I'm developping an application with CakePHP and I'm experiencing some problems with my DB.
The problem is that I have some tables with these kind of columns: sex (male/female), kind(image, video, text, song, link,...), ...

There is many way to solve this problem:

1. Creating linked tables listing sexes, kind of media, ... but I already have many tables so I don't want to overkill my DB.
2. Chose the data type ENUM for the columns but CakePHP don't like it.
3. Use 1,2,3,... as an index for these columns and map an array in PHP for each columns (not a good idea in my opinion, where to instantiate these aray ?, hard to know the real value of an item in the db, ...).
4. Use the real, full textual value of the column for each items in the table but it's redundant so loss of memory.

Personally, I think that the 4th possibility is the best but I would like to have other opinions or ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm thinking of an other way to solve it.
If I make a table for each list, I'll have many tables with just a few item and it's a problem for the maintenance of the DB.
But if I make a table called for ex. "app_contants" which have an id, a name and a category (ex.: '1', 'female', 'user_sex'). All tables which need a list item, will refer on this table and if I want a specific list of this table, I just have to make "$this->AppContants->find('list', array('conditions' => array('category', 'user_sex')));"

What do you think about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many solutions out there:

the array datasource for example

But I prefer working with class constants and static methods representing the enums:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

A few months ago I even added Enum support in my baking templates.
Makes them work out of the box - no one needs the database enums anyway.

Comment: Just make sure that you use App::import (or App::uses in 2.0) to include the model you want to access the enums from - in the file globally or just right above where you use it.

Comment: Hi Mark, I just updated my question, what do you think of the new solution I found ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that's sth I am using, as well. But you need to distinguish between real static ENUMS (where my method can and should be used) that will not change very often and can be hardcoded and those more dynamic ATTRIBUTES which you then can and should store as such in a related table as you describe. so do you want to edit them from the backend/website? Or are they fixed enums that only the programmer itself will change? that is what you should ask yourself and act accordingly. If you are not sure you can always but everything in the DB, of course :) It will cost you more joins/db calls, though.

Comment: Of course it will cost me more joins/db calls, but using it in combination with Apc cache it will just cost some ms sometimes. And when I want data which is related with these attribute, i don't need to make a join, just associate the id with the index of the list in the PHP script. Am I wrong ? Because I saw that when I call another model it always cost me ~10ms more for each although it's in cache...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, 3 is the way to go.

Create your array in app_controller, they will be available from all controllers.

You're right, the place the arrays need to be is in app_helper. You will need them to display the value to the user and to build the select items in the form, I was a bit tired I guess.

If for some reasons you need them in a model or controller, copy them in app_model and app_controller.

Comment: But what if I need it in the views or models ?

Comment: What do you think about putting the array in core.php using Configure::write(); and get them using ::read(); ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array datasource - and find::list for building sets of values for your forms. The array datasource gives you access exactly as if you had the data in a database, complete with relations and query filtering.

This also means you don't rely on enum @ the mysql level (making your app portable) and gives you datasource access to the arrays for testing. The other option I have used is very similar to the static enums technique linked above.